# How to solve the system of equation (simultanious) in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have to solve the following equation in matlab but I have some requirement step which I must follow.

x+y=17 
2x-y=10

"write the system of equation on Matrix form, 
AX=B, and plug in the matrix A and the vector B in Matlab. Solve the system 
of equations by calculating the inverse A-1, and then the product A-1 B using 
Matlab. Also, report the determinant of A in each question".

Comment: Tell the teacher there is much simpler way to do this: `syms x y;
[x,y]=solve(x+y==17,2*x-y==10,x,y)`

Answer (score 1):

Writing this as a matrix equation:

```
A * X = B
```

You have the following matrices:

```
A = [1 1; 2 -1];
B = [17; 10];
```

And you are looking for `X`.  For this you need the matlab `\` operator. I am going to leave it as an exercise for the student to figure out how to use that operator with this matrix and vector combination in order to produce `X` which is the solution of the equation.